Xamarin.Forms : change dynamically BarBackgroundColor
In a Xamarin.Forms program, how to dynamically change the BarBackgroundColor? I already changed the app.xaml file like this:
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--Global Styles-->
        <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="DarkOliveGreen" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>


But the color changes are not dynamic: they are read when the app is started, then can no longer be modified.
This works by making the following changes in the app.xaml.cs file:
DB_ParametreList = dbparametre.GetAllParametre();
            parametres = DB_ParametreList[0];
            if (parametres.WallpaperName == "wallpapers_4.png")
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ListeAchatsPage())
                {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#705502"),
                    BarTextColor = Color.White,
                };
            }
            else if (parametres.WallpaperName == "wallpapers_3.png")
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ListeAchatsPage())
                {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#09506B"),
                    BarTextColor = Color.White,
                };
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ListeAchatsPage())
                {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen,
                    BarTextColor = Color.White,
                };
            }

The problem comes from the MainPage which cannot be a NavigationPage because I have to display the icon of a Hambuger menu. Please help me to resolve this issue.
I tried all the solutions found on this forum, but none of them work because I have to display a hamburger menu on the MainPage

change the color dynamically based on what condition ?

I give the user the option to choose the homepage wallpaper, and depending on the image chosen (and saved in the database), I would like to change the color to match the background screen.
